# Get a list of FB users based on keyword post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I urgently need to extract some data from Facebook.  Appreciate if anyone can help.

I need to extract a list of facebook users (ID), his postings, his list of friends and his friends posting for the past 30 days based on a keyword found in the user's posting.  And the user who posted is from a specific country.

For example, I'm looking for a list of American/US-based users who had posted the word 'Woodstock 2013', the postings, and his friends who responded to the posting for the past 30 days.

I'm not very good at programming, so really appreciate the help.

thanks

Comment: You cannot query all the posts on facebook, only Public posts. Which is very, very small number compared to everything posted on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Just based on the nature of privacy and developer policy upheld in Facebook API this will not be possible. You need these users' explicit permissions.